Not getting correct predictions or boxes for yolov8 inference via tflite using c++ API
I am trying to get inference from yolov8 for object detection trained on the coco dataset. There is basically no official documentation for this but I tried to improvise based on the little amount of sample code provided. But pretty much everything about the output is wrong from the classes to the the number of bounding boxes and their locations and I have no idea why. I seem to have followed all the steps correctly and can't understand why it would fail so badly.
I am referring to this code given by Ultralytics.
#include "tensorflow/lite/model.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <random>

#define NUM_CLASSES_COCO 80

// Convert to letterbox format (copied from official implementation)
cv::Mat formatToSquare(const cv::Mat &source)
{
    int col = source.cols;
    int row = source.rows;
    int _max = MAX(col, row);
    cv::Mat result = cv::Mat::zeros(_max, _max, CV_8UC3);
    source.copyTo(result(cv::Rect(0, 0, col, row)));
    return result;
}

// Preprocessing function (adapted from official)
cv::Mat preprocess(cv::Mat &inputImage, int model_input_height, int model_input_width) {

    cv::Mat modelInputImage = formatToSquare(inputImage);
    cv::Mat blob;        

    //model height and width are same so doesn't matter in this case               
    cv::dnn::blobFromImage(modelInputImage, blob, 1.0 / 255.0, cv::Size(model_input_height, model_input_width), cv::Scalar(), true, false);

    return blob;
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat inputImage = //Assume loaded correctly;
    float modelConfidenceThreshold = 0.25;
    float modelScoreThreshold = 0.45;
    float modelNMSThreshold = 0.5;

    // path to a yolov8n tflite file trained on the coco dataset
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(model_path.c_str());

    tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
    tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*model, resolver)(&interpreter);

     // Allocate tensors
    if (interpreter->AllocateTensors() != kTfLiteOk)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to allocate tensors." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    int input = interpreter->inputs()[0];
    TfLiteIntArray *dims = interpreter->tensor(input)->dims; 

    cv::Mat preprocessed_image_blob = preprocess(inputImage, model_input_width, model_input_height);

    float *input_data = interpreter->typed_tensor<float>(input);
    std::memcpy(input_data, preprocessed_image_blob.data, sizeof(float) * model_input_width * model_input_height * model_input_channels);

    // Run inference
    if (interpreter->Invoke() != kTfLiteOk)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to invoke tflite interpreter." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    TfLiteTensor *output_tensor = interpreter->tensor(interpreter->outputs()[0]); //dims are (1, 84, 8400) as expected

    int rows, dimensions;
    rows = output_shape->data[2];
    dimensions = output_shape->data[1];

    float* data = output_tensor->data.f;

    // This is post processing part which is rather tricky.
    // Following the official implementation to reshape the initial 
    // tensor from (1, 84, 8400) to (8400, 84) and then proceed to 
    // flatten it. 

    cv::Mat temp(dimensions, rows, CV_32F, data); // need this to transpose to shape (8400, 84)

    cv::transpose(temp, temp);

    float* new_data = (float*) temp.data;

    float x_factor = image.cols/model_input_width;
    float y_factor = image.rows/model_input_height;
    
    std::vector<int> class_ids;
    std::vector<float> confidences;
    std::vector<cv::Rect> boxes;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        float *classes_scores = new_data + 4;

        cv::Mat scores(1, NUM_CLASSES_COCO, CV_32FC1, classes_scores);
        cv::Point class_id;
        double maxClassScore;

        cv::minMaxLoc(scores, 0, &maxClassScore, 0, &class_id);
        if (maxClassScore > modelScoreThreshold) 
        {
            confidences.push_back(maxClassScore);
            class_ids.push_back(class_id.x);

            float x = new_data[0];
            float y = new_data[1];
            float w = new_data[2];
            float h = new_data[3];

            int left = int((x - 0.5 * w) * x_factor);
            int top = int((y - 0.5 * h) * y_factor);

            int width = int(w * x_factor);
            int height = int(h * y_factor);

            boxes.push_back(cv::Rect(left, top, width, height));
        }

        new_data += dimensions;
    }
     
    // Perform NMS over the bounding boxes
    std::vector<int> nms_result;
    cv::dnn::NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, modelScoreThreshold, modelNMSThreshold, nms_result);

    std::cout << "after nms: " << nms_result.size() << std::endl;

    std::vector<Detection> detections{};
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < nms_result.size(); ++i)
    {
        int idx = nms_result[i];

        Detection result;
        result.class_id = class_ids[idx];
        result.confidence = confidences[idx];

        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(100, 255);
        result.color = cv::Scalar(dis(gen),
                                  dis(gen),
                                  dis(gen));

        result.box = boxes[idx];

        detections.push_back(result);
    }
}


So when I check the values in the detections vector I see that my class predictions are wrong as well as the length of the detections vector (it is always size 1 no matter what image it is). Both pre and post processing steps were copied from their official documentation (just that I had to adapt it for tflite) so I am not sure if there is anything wrong with that part. The tflite file has been confirmed to be correct exported via the python api too. I have no idea how to even begin debugging this. Would really appreciate any tips on it.
Edit: After a lot of debugging I was always to narrow down the issue so the output shape decoding. Upon fixing that the class predictions got much better (though not great).
Now the issue is the NMS does not work. I identified the reason for that to be the range of values of x, y, w, h which are in the range of (0, 1) for some reason, when they should be in the range of (0, dims_of_image). I am unable to understand how exactly the model can give out these values that it is not trained to give.
I can always confirm that my preprocessing steps are correct (cross verified from the correct python implementations). My output tensor shapes are also correct and my reshaping steps are also accurate. Only the values that the model outputs are wrong that for the bounding box coordinates. The class prediction scores are more or less fine.

Can you please put some comments in the code explaining the steps?

@kiner_shah I added the comments. Please also see the edit to my problem

Probably unrelated: move these three lines: std::random_device rd;  std::mt19937 gen(rd()); std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(100, 255); outside the for loop.

@kiner_shah It just creates a random color to assign to the boxes while visualizing, it has nothing to do with the inferences as such

Need to reshape the input from [1, 3, 640, 640] to [1, 640, 640, 3].

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
